# Temperature in a calorimeter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, heat

> A closed calorimeter of negligible water equivalent contains 1kg ice at 0 degree Celsius. 1kg of steam at 100 degrees Celsius is pumped into it. Find the resultant temperature of the mixture.

I did the standard approach. Heat absorbed by ice = Heat lost by steam. I took the change in temperature as $\Delta\theta_{i}$ and $\Delta\theta_{s}$. I will use sub $s$ for steam and sub $i$ for ice.

$$Q_\text{ice} = Q_\text{steam}$$

$$m_is_f + m_is_w\Delta\theta_i = m_ss_v + m_ss_w\Delta\theta_s$$

Where $s_f$ is specific heat of fusion of water, $s_w$ is specific heat of water and $s_v$ is specific heat of vaporization of water.

Since $\Delta\theta_s = 100 - \Delta\theta_i$,

$$m_is_f + m_is_w\Delta\theta_i = m_ss_v + m_ss_w(100 - \Delta\theta_i)$$

$$m_is_f + m_is_w\Delta\theta_i = m_ss_v + 100m_ss_w - m_ss_w\Delta\theta_i$$

$$\Delta\theta_i(m_is_w + m_ss_w) = m_ss_v + 100m_ss_w - m_is_f$$
and thus
\begin{align}\Delta\theta_i&=\frac{m_ss_v + 100m_ss_w - m_is_f}{m_is_w + m_ss_w}\\&= \frac{1000g\times2230\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{g}} + 100\,\mathrm{K}\times1000\,\mathrm{g}\times4.18\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{gK}} - 1000g\times334\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{g}}}{1000\,\mathrm{g}\times4.18\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{gK}} + 1000\,\mathrm{g}\times4.18\,\mathrm{\frac{J}{gK}}}\\&= 276.79\,\mathrm{K}\end{align}

Which makes no sense. I know I am making some naive error. But I have gone through this problem at least ten times but to no avail.

Comment: As per our [recommendation on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715), "It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another technique for this type of question is to *assume* that the final result is all the water in some specific state, and find the net energy change to achieve this.  If it's non-zero, as is likely, you have one uniform system to make any necessary correction.

For example, assume that the final situation here is all liquid water at 100° C. This is wrong, as shown by Wojciech Morawiec, but no matter.

To reach this state, we must add heat energy to the kilo of ice:$$Heat_{added}=1000\times 334+1000 \times 100\times 4.184=752,400 joules$$

To condense the kilo of steam to liquid water at 100° C, we must remove heat:$$Heat_{Removed}=1000 \times 2230=2,230,000 joules$$ So, now we have 2 kilograms of boiling hot liquid water, but we need, for zero net heat flow, to stuff back in $(2,230,000-752,000)$ or $1,471,000 joules$. (See, the guess $was$ wrong) This is enough to "re-vaporize" $\frac{1,471,000}{2230}=660$ grams of water.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning and most of the calculation is fine.

The problem here is that condensing 1 kg of steam gives off so much energy (2230 kJ), that it is enough to heat the system to a temperature that is above the initial steam temperature (naively calculating). This excess heat will be absorbed by the water in an attempt to vaporize all of it, but since we used a part of that heat to melt the ice and also we now have an additional kilogram of water, it won't be enough.

So the correct answer to this problem would be "The resultant temperature of the mixture will be 100 °C, because 2230 kJ is more than enough heat to raise the temperature of 2 kg of water to its boiling point, but not enough to convert all of it to steam."